# using Tinymce for django error.

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I am trying to use TinyMCE Editor in django for textarea. I followed the instructions given on django-tinymce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#python-code which give me a error

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/home/

Django Version: 1.6.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'tinymce')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/hussain/django/ali/ali/views.py" in HomePage
  6.     print " form :: ",form
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/utils/encoding.py" in <lambda>
  60.         klass.__str__ = lambda self: self.__unicode__().encode('utf-8')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in __str__
  103.         return self.as_table()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in as_table
  223.             errors_on_separate_row = False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in _html_output
  186.                     'field': six.text_type(bf),
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in __str__
  425.         return self.as_widget()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in as_widget
  475.         return widget.render(name, self.value(), attrs=attrs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/forms/widgets.py" in render
  572.         options = self.render_options(choices, value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/forms/widgets.py" in render_options
  528.         for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/forms/models.py" in __iter__
  1044.             for obj in self.queryset.all():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  96.         self._fetch_all()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  854.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  220.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  710.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  781.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  69.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  99.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  450.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /home/
Exception Value: no such table: django_site
```

I feel to stupid to not get this. :'(.

these are my files.

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for ali project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Django settings for corating project.

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

print 'BASE_DIR ',BASE_DIR
print 'PROJECT_DIR ',PROJECT_DIR
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '-=153zwy^8$sz%gsw#kb377pp@r3wmcer(4tc$j-h4(^3s+zw+'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []




# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tinymce',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ali.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ali.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static_root')
# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(STATIC_URL, "js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js")
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_URL, "js/tiny_mce")

print "TINYMCE_JS_ROOT  ",TINYMCE_JS_ROOT
print "TINYMCE_JS_URL   ",TINYMCE_JS_URL


TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/home/hussain/django/ali/ali/templates/',
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE


class FlatPageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30}))

    class Meta:
        model = FlatPage
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from page.forms import FlatPageForm 

def HomePage(request):
    form = FlatPageForm()
    print " form :: ",form
    return render_to_response('HomePage.html',{'form':form})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from ali.views import HomePage
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'ali.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    #url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^home/', 'ali.views.HomePage' ),
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls') ),

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have installed `flatpages` app. Also `flatpages` app depends in [`sites framework`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/sites/#module-django.contrib.sites) Follow the steps in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/flatpages/) to get it right:

--- excerpts --

To install the flatpages app, follow these steps:

1. Install the sites framework by adding 'django.contrib.sites' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting, if it’s not already in there.
2. Also make sure you’ve correctly set SITE_ID to the ID of the site the settings file represents. This will usually be 1 (i.e. SITE_ID = 1, but if you’re using the sites framework to manage multiple sites, it could be the ID of a different site.